# How did List.Remove remove floats from lists?

Tags: c#, list, hash, collections

If we cannot compare float based on equality because of the limitation machine accuracy, how does the `Remove` method of the various C# collections types (like `List` and `HashSet`) work?

I assume for C# List, given it is implemented in array, it is simply a O(n) traversal to find out whether the element is in, and if it is, remove it. For HashSet I assume it to be a typical O(1) algorithm is: calculate the float's hash and see whether the hash exists and if it does, remove it.

**Question 1: For List, how do they determine whether two floats are the same while they do the traversal? Simply ==?**

Based on what I experimented I think this is the case.

```
var floatList = new List<float>(){0.1001f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f};
floatList.ShowAll("Before");
floatList.Remove(0.1f);
floatList.ShowAll("After");

//Before
//0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 
//After
//0.1001 0.2 0.3 0.4
//0.1001 is NOT removed
```

But, if I changed the first element to be something like `0.1000000001f` then

```
//Before
//0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 
//After
//0.2 0.3 0.4
//0.1000000001f is removed
```

So **Question 2: if I guessed right and C# is indeed using == to compare float while doing the Remove method is there anyway to change that?**

The above behaviors do not change when I change List to HashSet. This is kind of expected because I think `GetHashCode()` should always agree with `Equals()`, so using hashcode to compare essentially has the same accuracy as using ==.

So **Question 3: how is hash of float calculated?**

---

Note: this is the extension method I used:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt
{
    public static void ShowAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> iEnumerable, string title)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(title);
        foreach (var ele in iEnumerable)
        {
            Console.Write(ele + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET source code is available to everyone and you can even step through it in the debugger. You don't need to ask questions like this because you can see for yourself.

Comment: Wasn't aware. Thanks

Comment: [This](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) might be the place to start.